# How the set the correct file path using os.path.isfile() method?

Tags: python, filepath, os.path

I'm using os.path.isfile() to check is the file exist on the path I specified, then return either TRUE or FALSE, it should read the file path in a textfile, in this case: qcompath.txt,  line by line using line.rstrip().

```
PROPRIETARY_FCL = "qcompath.txt"
    OUT_FILE = "compare_output.txt"
    
    outFile = open(OUT_FILE, "a")
    
    with open(PROPRIETARY_FCL, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        
        for line in lines:
            print("Comparing "+ line.rstrip() + "\n")
            outFile.write(line.rstrip() + "\n====================================\n")
            a10_file_exist = os.path.isfile(PROPRIETARY_A10_PATH + line.rstrip())
            a11_file_exist = os.path.isfile(PROPRIETARY_A11_PATH + line.rstrip())
```

but the result returned, the ***a10_file_exist*** and ***a11_file_exist*** is always FALSE which is wrong, because the file path, the file did exist in my local directory according to the text file, it just cannot find the file that's why it return FALSE.

Below is the file path I set, I'm not sure whether the way I set here is correct or not by including the W:/.

```
PROPRIETARY_A10_PATH = 'W:/android/vendor/qcom/non-hlos/'
PROPRIETARY_A11_PATH = 'W:/green/vendor/qcom/non-hlos/'
```

I run this script at W:/ (means this script is saved under **W:/**, same level with **android** and **green**). **compare_output.txt** will also generated at this level.

Below is the example of line in the textfile, "qcompath.txt"

```
modem_proc/core/debugtools/task/src/mobile.c
modem_proc/lte/configs/configs_xml/NA/MKZ_BELL/mcfg_sw_gen_Commercial.xml
modem_proc/mcfg/configs/mcfg_sw/mbn_sw.txt
modem_proc/mcfg/configs/mcfg_sw/MSI_AMP_oem_sw.txt
```

**A example of complete file path is

```
W:/android/vendor/qcom/non-hlos/modem_proc/core/debugtools/task/src/mobile.c
```

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: W:/ is actually a server where I map it as a drive, and all those files are in local in my laptop. I'm using Windows, but I run this script using MobaXterm terminal, it is linux i think, where I SSH into the server

Comment: Okay, so if you SSH into the server and for example type `ls W:/android/vendor/qcom/non-hlos/modem_proc/core/debugtools/task/src/` you see the `mobile.c` file?

Comment: I have to cd into the W:/ level and I only able to see the file by using
`ls android/vendor/qcom/non-hlos/modem_proc/core/debugtools/task/src/`

Comment: I think the problem is at the W:/, where this network/server path cant be read by the script